# Representations of a subgroup of a finite grup

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$.

Let's say that $H$ has $h$ irreducible representations $\psi_1,\psi_2,...,\psi_h,$ and $G$ has $g$ irreducible representations, $\rho_1,\rho_2,...,\rho_g$.

- Is it automatically true that $h\leq g$?
- Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for a representation $\rho_i$ to be induces by some $\psi_j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first bullet-point: no, that inequality does not always hold. For example, there is a non-Abelian finite group $G$ of order $21$ which has exactly $5$ inequivalent irreducible complex representations, of degree $1,1,1,3$ and $3$. But $G$ has an Abelian subgroup $H$ of order $7$ which has $7$ inequivalent one-dimensional complex irreducible representations.

(Removed part of answer since second bullet point changed).